# creating dataframe with TOP10 ordered by frequency unique values from another dataframe in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a dataframe with a large number of observations of 6 variables. The source dataframe looks like this:
[image: source dataframe]

I need a new dataframe with `TOP10` ordered by frequency `TDT_PRD_ID` (unique values).
I tried to return one values using apply function like this:

`apply(data, 2, function(x) names(which.max(x)))`

but I don't know how to create `TOP10`. Can you help me, please?

I need something like this:
[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoqTI.png)

Comment: Do you want `library(data.table);
setDT(data, key="TDT_PRD_ID");
data[1:10]` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to sort by `TDT_QTY` then you can just do (assuming you want the most frequent first):

```
TOP10 <- data[order(data$TDT_QTY,decreasing=TRUE),]
```

And if you only want the top 10 after that:

```
TOP10[1:10,]
```